# WebBrowser Control inside XBAP application: allow cookies

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, session-cookies, xbap

I have a WebBrowser control (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser + WindowsFormsHost) inside XBAP application. The problem is that when I "Navigate()" to website that requires cookies and I put my credentials, WebBrowser does not set the "session" number parameter in the "Cookie" property of the GET (HTTP) method and the login fails. I suspect that the WebBrowser does not accept cookies (or session cookies?). I tried to use IInternetSecurityManager in this way:

```
    public static bool TryAllowCookies(Uri uri)
    {
        IInternetSecurityManager securityManager = (IInternetSecurityManager)new InternetSecurityManager();
        int policy = 0;
        Guid context = Guid.Empty;

        int hr = securityManager.ProcessUrlAction(uri.ToString(),
                                     URLACTION_COOKIES_SESSION | URLACTION_COOKIES_ENABLED | URLACTION_COOKIES |
                     URLACTION_COOKIES_SESSION_THIRD_PARTY | URLACTION_COOKIES_THIRD_PARTY,
                     ref policy,
                     Marshal.SizeOf(policy),
                     ref context,
                     Marshal.SizeOf(context),
                     PUAF_DEFAULT, 0);

                     return (hr == 0) && policy == URLPOLICY_ALLOW;
    }
```

ProcessUrlAction returs always True, but does not work.

I found no complete example of how to use IInternetSecurityManager with WebBrowser control. 
The same control instead in a windows form application works perfectly.

HTTP sniffing:

WEBBROWSER FROM XBAP APPLICATION (NOT WORKS):

```
GET /cgi-bin/xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/xaml+xml, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, */*
Referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/yyy.yyy
Accept-Language: it
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2)
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: language=it; user=smith
```

WEBBROWSER FROM WINDOWS FORM APPLICATION (WORKS)

```
GET /cgi-bin/xxx.xxx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/xaml+xml, application/msword, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, */*
Referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/cgi-bin/yyy.yyy
Accept-Language: it
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2)
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: language=en; user=smith; session=2a9cffb0babea74e3432fc9805470faa; current_page=
```

thank you,
Riccardo

Comment: I do not see where you are setting the "session" number, what am I missing?